# Where to find native speakers for acceptability tests

Tags: resource-request, field-linguistics

I just wondered if any of y'all know if there's a website which can find you native speakers in various languages to get judgments on the acceptability of sentences.

Answer (score 3):

I will say "Not Ling SE", because such questions are likely to be closed as being language specific grammar questions (not about linguistics): though there are language-specific versions of SE where you might ask grammaticality judgments about Chinese, Esperanto, French and so on. I think it would be worth asking on Ling Meta whether as a matter of policy we can accept lists of acceptability judgments, but I'm fairly confident that the majority answer is "No". Reddit might accept such questions. Bear in mind that there are no guarantees that responders actually speak the language. Such is the nature of the internet.

There have been specific-language websites, for instance there was a Kurdish language website. but again you don't know for sure that the responder actually speaks Hawrami, or Sorani, or Kurmanji. There is certainly no generic all-languages repository of native speakers willing to provide grammaticality judgments. The closest you can get (not close at all) is Forvo, which is a repository of audio recordings which in principle could include any language. In theory, you can contact contributors.

Comment: There are, however, chat rooms on certain Se sites. Certainly, folks in the EL&U chat room are sometimes happy to help out other members, and you'll often get many users chipping in. Depends on the site though and whether the cat room's fairly active.